# Text on a shape

Tags: android, android-widget

I want to acheive somthing like this:

[image]

If we talk about the encircled one. I guess `25` will be the TextView and `2` will be the background image of that Text View. Here, `2` represents number of events on that day. But number of events can be dynamic.

How can I create a background shape with dynamic text on it?
Is it possible?

### Edit

`Mission Accomplished` :-)

By extending **NPike's** code I've achieved the required design. Although I started with something else in my mind. But while working on it I changed my mind and now I think I have a better design than what I initially planned to have.

Here is my design now:

[image]

Here is my code:

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.TextView;

```
public class MonthlyCalTextView extends TextView {
    private Paint mPaint;
    private String strNoOfEvents;


    public MonthlyCalTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, String noOfEvents) {
        super(context, attrs); 

        strNoOfEvents = ( Integer.parseInt(noOfEvents)>100 )? "100+":noOfEvents;
        strNoOfEvents = (strNoOfEvents.equals("0")) ? "":strNoOfEvents;
        mPaint = new Paint();
        mPaint.setTypeface( Typeface.defaultFromStyle(Typeface.BOLD) );
        mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        mPaint.setColor(Color.rgb(223, 223, 223));
    }

    public MonthlyCalTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        mPaint.setTextSize(35);
        canvas.drawText(strNoOfEvents, getMeasuredWidth()-mPaint.measureText(strNoOfEvents)-3, getMeasuredHeight()-3, mPaint);


        super.onDraw(canvas);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) { 
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

        // grow view dimensions to account for circle
        setMeasuredDimension(getMeasuredWidth(), getMeasuredHeight());
    }

}
```

and this is how I am calling it:

```
Random rand = new Random();
// Just for demo assuming that the no. of events will be between 0-125
int min=0, max=125;
String randomNum = String.valueOf( rand.nextInt(max - min + 1) + min );
MonthlyCalTextView tvData=new MonthlyCalTextView(CalendarMonthlyFragment.activity, null, randomNum);
```

Comment: Could you pls accept an answer if your issue is resolved so that it is not unanswered ? tnks :)

Comment: You can create your own drawable to draw text on top of the circle using canvas.

Comment: @lokoko -- I will accept the answer. Don't worry :-P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create your own extension of TextView that overrides onDraw to draw a circle.

Here is a brief example:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Paint.Style;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class CircleTextView extends TextView {

    private static final int PADDING = 15;
    private Paint mCirclePaint;


    public CircleTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs); 

        mCirclePaint = new Paint();
        mCirclePaint.setStyle(Style.FILL);
        mCirclePaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        mCirclePaint.setColor(Color.GREEN); 
    }


    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        // draw circle at center of canvas
        canvas.drawCircle(getMeasuredWidth()/2, getMeasuredHeight()/2, PADDING, mCirclePaint);
        super.onDraw(canvas);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) { 
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

        // grow view dimensions to account for circle
        setMeasuredDimension(resolveSize(getMeasuredWidth()+(PADDING*2), widthMeasureSpec), resolveSize(getMeasuredHeight()+(PADDING*2), heightMeasureSpec));
    }

}
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't know much about `onDraw`. Can you please explain where in the above code have you mentioned that the text would be inside the circle? or it's not there in your example?

Comment: While creating an object of this text view, what should I send in `AttributeSet attrs` ?

Comment: I sent null in place of attrs. I have achieved the desired results. I am accepting your asnwer as you gave the basic idea. I have also uploaded my code that would soon be visible.

Answer (score 3):

Try something like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:clickable="true" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="10dp"
    android:layout_height="10dp"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:background="@drawable/sample_image" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/some_title"
        android:layout_width="10dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="3dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

and in the java class inflate the relative layout into a view and the textView into a findById of the inflated view.

This is the way the native calendar app. shows the Today view.

Comment: In fact I am new in Android Dev. Can you please provide some link where this point might be explained in detail?

Comment: You could dwld the sample apps from the sdk and check the calendar app in specific. Check the implementation of the Today section.

Comment: Are you familiar with gridView ? if not then i think you might want to research on that before this because your calendar view would be a gridView that you would have to construct.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridView.html
after that you could check the relative layout
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html